# Create Bash Script to Wait and then Run

Tags: bash, shell-script

What I am basically trying to achieve is to automate something I do every time I start work.

In this order, I

1. VPN connection
2. Open new `gnome-terminal` tab
3. SSH into a remote machine

I have this so far:

```
WID=$(xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"| awk '{print $5}')
xdotool windowfocus $WID
xdotool type --delay 1 --clearmodifiers "sudo openvpn --config 'conn1.ovpn'"
xdotool key Return

xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
wmctrl -i -a $WID
sleep 1

while ! $(/usr/bin/fping -q 192.168.0.5); do sleep 1;done

xdotool type --delay 3 --clearmodifiers "ssh machine1"
sleep 3
xdotool key Return
```

The problem I am having is that the SSH commands require the VPN connection to be open first. I thought that by putting the last sleep command in, that the code would wait for 3 seconds before hitting enter.

What is actually happening is that the `openvpn` command is not running until after the last sleep, so the SSH command fails.

Can someone please point me in the direction I need to be heading for this.

Answer (score 1):

Put a waiting loop before starting ssh:

```
while ! $(/usr/bin/fping -q <openvpn remote endpoint ip>); do sleep 1;done
```

Comment: When I do this, the VPN connection won't run. The new tab opens but both tabs appear to be waiting for the IP to be available

Comment: @Wildcard27 do you mean that with the ping loop the VPN doesn't go up anymore?